# What was Sri Adi Sankaracharya's role in the history of the Jagannath temple at Puri?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, jagan-natha

I read in one biography of Sri Adi Sankaracharya that He reinstated the deities of Sri Jagannath, Balarama, Suvadra and Sudarsana at the Puri temple.They were buried underground because of some reason.

Is it true?

What was the exact role of Sri Adi Sankaracharya in the history of the Puri Jagannath temple?

The deities seem too big to be taken to other place and get buried.

Can anyone throw any light on this?

Kindly cite proper source.Thanks.

Comment: Which biography book are you reading?

Comment: @Pandya I have read one bengali biography by Swami Apurvananda, a disciple of Sri Sarada Devi.